# Python connectorx odbc connections

Tags: pandas, odbc, python-polars

Python Polars uses connectorx to connect to databases under the hood.
**Does connectorx support ODBC connections?**

I would prefer to work without pandas, which can interface with pyodbc and is the fallback connection method reccomended by the polars documentation.

Comment: These links may be of help: https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x/issues/215  https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x#sources

Comment: There’s some discussions here that may also be of interest: https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x/discussions/61

Answer (score 1):

Would this be what you are looking for?

```
query = "SELECT * FROM mytable"

username = 'myuser'
password = '123'
server = '00.00.00'
port = 1111
database = 'mydatabase'

conn = f"mssql+pyodbc://{username}:{password}@{server}:{port}/{database}"
df = pl.read_sql(query, conn)
```

While experimenting with polars and pandas connections I've noticed pandas `pd.read_sql` to be faster for smaller queries while polars `pl.read_sql` was significantly faster to load large(r) tables.